# python script to match video clip from a larger video stream

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, video-processing, audio-fingerprinting

I want to develop a script in python that can be used to identify a video clips contained in a video stream.

Could you please suggest me some python libraries or any example scripts to start compare to video files

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may be of use - it is image rather than video but the same principles will apply:

- https://realpython.com/blog/python/fingerprinting-images-for-near-duplicate-detection/

More generally, the technology you are most likely interested in is usually referred to as video fingerprinting. This is a fairly dynamic domain so its worth doing some googling to get a feel for the latest state of the art.